# What is the difference between variables A and _A in Prolog?

Tags: variables, prolog

What is the difference between `A` and `_A` in `a(A,B):-b(A)` and `a(_A,B):-b(_A)`, respectively?

Comment: Even if they will behave the same at runtime, the prolog interpreter/compiler usually has different lint rules for variables starting with underscore.

Answer (score 0):

The variables `A` and `_A` are exactly identical. . . except that they are different variables with different names.

The variable `_` is special in prolog, but not so variables with names starting with `_`.

Answer (score -1):

In Prolog, the variables `A` and `_A` behave the same way, as shown below.

```
?- portray_clause(a(A,B):-b(A)).
a(A, _) :-
    b(A).
true.

?- portray_clause(a(_A,B):-b(_A)).
a(A, _) :-
    b(A).
true.
```

Comment: If you really want to make a self answered question (and I see you are trying to do it a lot) having some value, make sure the question itself is making sense and useful (for this one I do not see any motivation), and the answer is full and is containing all the required references. Providing a specific example to prove some point is not sufficient.

Comment: I meant interpreters do not report singleton variables that begin with _. (http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~billw/dictionaries/prolog/dontcare.html)